# ClickOnce only publishing a single project of three

Tags: asp.net, clickonce, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS2013. Currently I have versions 1.0.0.1 -> 1.0.0.6 and have created a new version (1.0.0.7). When attempting to carry on with the existing system  I follow the paths of mainSolution -> project -> properties project ->publish ->publish wizard. The problem I'm having however is that it is only publishing 1 of the 3 projects, to be specific it looks as though it's creating the entire solution into one file instead of it being in it's individual .exe files.
 What I'm attempting to do is add the new version to the existing structre (currently stored on a common server). It has to house all 3 of the projects of course. When I am currently attempting to publish the solution, I am only able to get a .application (clickOnce)  as well with it's respective .exe.config.deply and .exe.manifest files. In the existing file structures I have it shows the three C# projects .exe, and the "main launcher's" .exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have been able to understand about the ClickOnce deployment system is that it you don't publish a solution.  You publish a project.  If that project has dependencies, then those dependencies will go along for the ride, but if you simply have other unrelated projects in the solution they don't automatically get included.  What you can do, however, is build the EXE files from the other projects and include them in the main project as content.  You may have to set the build output folder of the other projects to be the main project's folder, but I recommend against that because I think you very specifically have to set the "Build Action" property for each extra executable as "Content" to include them.  You also need to check your "Application Files" under the Publish tab to make sure the exe files are included with the click once release.

I am using 2012, so this all may not match perfectly.

The following has a discussion on expired certificates, and proposes some possible workarounds that allow using a test certificate to extend the existing signing certificate, that should still work for people with updates.

[Certificate Expiration in ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx)

But when you change the signing certificate of a ClickOnce deployment, the customers may have to uninstall the application and install the new version with the new signing certificate.

Comment: I believe you may be correct Ted, I'll give it a shot at least. Thanks!

Comment: Well I've attempted your suggestion Ted, with no luck. Although I have the proper .exe files in the folder, my cert is different (which I think may be the cause of the problem). When attempting to use the applications "check for updates" option, it doesn't find the folder or the new versions despite the same naming conventions. The only difference at this point would be the cert, which leads me to believe it's part of the problem.

Comment: Hmm.  I always thought the updates were exclusively URL based, so that as long as you published to the same folder older versions would find the new ones, but I'm very new to signing code myself and haven't had any efforts at transitioning from one certificate to another.

Comment: Well you can do it via URL, but you can also do it using a UNC path.    My current thought process is pointed at the cert. With a existing clickOnce application file being created, and the existing cert structure being a incremental one, would a different (self signed) cert be causing the issue?  (currently its 1000.pfx ->1006.pfx). When attempting to do this on my local host, I've created a self signed cert.